# BigQuery external queries with union all

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to show data in BigQuery from two external queries
I'm trying to use UNION ALL, but I'm getting the data as join
This is what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
EXTERNAL_QUERY("connection_path1", "query1")
UNION ALL
EXTERNAL_QUERY("connection_pat2", "query2")
)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Syntax error: Expected keyword JOIN but got keyword UNION at
```

How can I achieve UNION ALL in big-query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below instead

```
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("connection_path1", "query1")
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("connection_pat2", "query2")
```